# meaning of the phrase "come a-knocking"?

Tags: meaning

It is from [Crash Coursd A&P](https://youtu.be/-XQcnO4iX_U). The phrase was at 3 minute and 33 second. Here is context:

> When puberty comes a-knocking, the hypothalamus starts realeasing gonadotropin-releasing hormone, or GnRH.

If *a* in the phrase was used for *and*, then would it not be grammatically correct to say *when puberty comes a-knock*?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KCjkuF5F3kk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If a in the phrase was used for and,

The *a* does not mean *and* although that is a decent guess.

> When puberty comes a-knocking

You essentially can remove the "a-" from *knocking* to get the intended meaning

> When puberty comes knocking

The a- is known as [A-prefixing](https://ygdp.yale.edu/phenomena/a-prefixing) and is a feature of some dialects. In this case, it gives it a less formal colloquial feel.